# Code: 403 Message:Permission denied Google wallet web Api

Tags: python, actions-on-google

I am currently following this guide to create cards for the google wallet: https://developers.google.com/wallet/retail/loyalty-cards/web

I did all the steps before and I am at the step "Create Passes object".

This is my current code:

```
KEY_FILE_PATH = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS",
                               "/Users/me/key.json")

ISSUER_ID = os.environ.get("WALLET_ISSUER_ID", "MY_Issuer_Id")

CLASS_ID = os.environ.get("WALLET_CLASS_ID", "My_Wallet_class_id")

USER_ID = os.environ.get("WALLET_USER_ID", "my@email.com")

OBJECT_ID = "%s.%s-%s" % (ISSUER_ID, re.sub(r"[^\w.-]", "_", USER_ID), CLASS_ID)



credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    KEY_FILE_PATH,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/wallet_object.issuer"])

http_client = AuthorizedSession(credentials)


OBJECT_URL = "https://walletobjects.googleapis.com/walletobjects/v1/loyaltyObject/"
object_payload = {
    "id": OBJECT_ID,
    "classId": f"{ISSUER_ID}.{CLASS_ID}",
    "heroImage": {
        "sourceUri": {
            "uri": "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3723/11177041115_6e6a3b6f49_o.jpg",
            "description": "Test heroImage description"
        }
    },
    "textModulesData": [
        {
            "header": "Test text module header",
            "body": "Test text module body"
        }
    ],
    "linksModuleData": {
        "uris": [
            {
                "kind": "walletobjects#uri",
                "uri": "http://maps.google.com/",
                "description": "Test link module uri description"
            },
            {
                "kind": "walletobjects#uri",
                "uri": "tel:6505555555",
                "description": "Test link module tel description"
            }
        ]
    },
    "imageModulesData": [
        {
            "mainImage": {
                "kind": "walletobjects#image",
                "sourceUri": {
                    "kind": "walletobjects#uri",
                    "uri": "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3738/12440799783_3dc3c20606_b.jpg",
                    "description": "Test image module description"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "barcode": {
        "kind": "walletobjects#barcode",
        "type": "qrCode",
        "value": "Test QR Code"
    },
    "state": "active",
    "accountId": "Test account id",
    "accountName": "Test account name",
    "loyaltyPoints": {
        "balance": {
            "string": "800"
        },
        "label": "Points"
    },
    "locations": [
        {
            "kind": "walletobjects#latLongPoint",
            "latitude": 37.424015499999996,
            "longitude": -122.09259560000001
        }
    ]
}

object_response = http_client.get(OBJECT_URL + OBJECT_ID)
if object_response.status_code == 404:
    object_response = http_client.post(
        OBJECT_URL,
        json=object_payload
    )

print("object GET or POST response:", object_response.text)
```

And I get his error:

object GET or POST response: {
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Permission denied.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Permission denied.",
"domain": "walletobjects",
"reason": "permissionDenied"
}
]
}
}

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code and request is working fine.

If your request was malformed you would receive a 400 - Bad Request.

Are you sure that your key (for authorization) is (still) valid? Maybe it expired?

Another possible mistake could be here:

```
object_response = http_client.get(OBJECT_URL + OBJECT_ID)
```

Make sure that that String is concatated correctly (maybe a "/" is Missing)

Anyways I can't spot any other error (but granted, I don't know the modules you are using in this case)